How to call make install after building the target
I have a library project mk_lib which creates a shared library mk_lib.so when built using make command. I then install this library to /usr/local/lib/ using the command sudo make install. The library header file lib.h is also installed to /usr/local/include/ using install command. The main executable makes use of the mk_lib library. This library is made available using sudo ldconfig command which makes path /usr/local/lib/ as library search path during executable mk_demo creation. I want to know is it possible to perform the three library related actions (creation using make and installation using sudo make install to copy library to /usr/local/lib/ and install header file lib.h to usr/local/include) as one command instead of executing them separately. Basically if library build is successful then automatically call install commands else don't.
mk_demo/main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "lib.h"

int main(int, char**){
    std::cout << "Hello, from mk_demo!\n";
    std::cout << add(2, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << subtract(2, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << multiply(2, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << divide(2, 3) << std::endl;
}

mk_demo/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(mk_demo VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mk_lib)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mk_lib)

mk_demo/build/
mk_demo/mk_lib/lib.h
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

int add(const int a, const int b);
int subtract(const int a, const int b);
int multiply(const int a, const int b);
int divide(const int a, const int b);

#endif

mk_demo/mk_lib/lib.cpp
#include "lib.h"

int add(const int a, const int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int subtract(const int a, const int b) {
    return a - b;
}

int multiply(const int a, const int b) {
    return a * b;
}

int divide(const int a, const int b) {
    return a / b;
}

mk_demo/mk_lib/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(mk_lib VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED lib.h lib.cpp)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION /usr/local/lib)

mk_demo/mk_lib/build/

This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need to install the library immediately after building it? make && make install has been an idiom for decades, with several good reasons.

@Botje If I'm not wrong when I execute mk_demo make, it will call make of mk_lib and creates the lib inside mk_demo/mk_lib/build right? If it is, then for linking this to mk_demo target I need the library to be installed to /usr/local/lib to get rid of linker issues

No, cmake takes care of that for you. It even tells mk_demo where to look in your build tree using RPATH. If you are not able to run mk_demo from your build tree, edit your question to that effect and include the output.

ok... does this work even when one .so file links to another .so file? Because RPATH only works in case of executables if I'm not wrong?

I think that should just work. Try it and see..
